# Finding values between min and max in 1d array in Javascript

Tags: javascript, binary-search-tree, search-tree

I have an array with values and I need to find all values between min and max. I believe I need to construct some kind of search tree, is that correct? I want something like:

```
var values : number[] = tree.findBetween(min : number, max: number);
```

The performance of the search is the main criterion.

Also, I don't need to change the tree (add/remove values) once it is constructed.

What is it that I need? A binary-tree? A balanced search tree? A static search tree?

Where do I start?

Comment: sort the array and iterate the values between min and max.

Comment: No, you don't need to construct a tree as a data structure. Binary search works directly on a sorted array.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to [@bergi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1048572/bergi) for the answer, I really do not need to construct a search tree to perform a binary search on a sorted array, so I should be able to find my values and get the part of the array between them.

Just for curiosity, I found an [interesting article](https://consulity.net/content/JSBinarySearchVsArrayFilter.aspx) comparing the performance of the binary search with an ordinary search - loop through the array. The article somehow mistakenly includes the time to sort the array into the search time - you are supposed to use the binary search only if you have a sorted array (if you can pre-sort it before of the performance critical period). I run the code with up to some 1e7 items and the binary search on sorted arrays takes 0 milliseconds as compared to tens of milliseconds for simply looping the array.

In the end, this is the fastest implementation of binary search I could find.
https://oli.me.uk/2014/12/17/revisiting-searching-javascript-arrays-with-a-binary-search/

Thanks for everyone's help.

Answer (score 1):

Oh, sorry, my Globish sometimes plays tricks on me. Otherwise, I do not see too much where the difficulty is for such a question, but here is always a new answer (hoping that this time I will not be next to the plate)

outside this :
**what could it be more faster than a native js method ?**

```js
const
  MaxValue = 50,
  MinValue = 10
  ;

let
  ArrayOrigin = [12, 5, 8, 130, 44, 25, 14, 42, 36 ],
  ArrayInLimits = ArrayOrigin.filter( elm=>  elm>MinValue && elm<MaxValue)
  ;

  console.log( ...ArrayInLimits );
```

Comment: Could you please translate your answer to English? This is an [English-only](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/13676) site.

Comment: @4castle : oki, I have translate it.  that was not the worth for negative point... (and how is your French ?)

Comment: sorry, the assumption was therefore wrong, this is someone else who downvote without explanations, even a French guy can do that ! :)

Comment: A binary search does not iterate all elements, but Array.filter definitely does.  It will be significantly slower because of the huge size of the array.

Comment: Ok, I'm gonna start to translate all the links in this subject, give me time please ;)